# How to detect locale configuration changes in Android Auto?

Tags: android-auto

Android Auto is able to detect changes in the uiMode when triggering the night / day commands in the simulator. This results in the system calling `onCarConfigurationChanged`.

Is it possible to do something similar when the user changes the system language in a connected mobile phone? My use case is to refresh the UI projected in Android Auto when the system language is adjusted. Right now, changes seems to be taken only when killing the session and starting a new one. I basically do this by disconnecting and connecting the device to Android Auto. The next time the app starts it shows the right language.

Is it actually possible to force the recreation of the CarSession by using any existing API?